# Vectorize selection of the larger of several values from a string in a dataframe

Tags: r, filter

> Given a dataframe with multiple comma-separated values in some cells, **how can I vectorize creation of a new column containing the larger of the two values?**

```
mydf <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=c(paste(1,3,2, sep=','),paste(1,2,3, sep=','),paste(4,3,21, sep=',')),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

**Input:**

```
  a      b
1 1      1,3,2
2 2      1,2,3
3 3     4,3,21
```

**Desired output:**

```
  a          b      c
1 1      1,3,2      3
2 2      1,2,3      3
3 3     4,3,21     21
```

**Hideous code, that generates desired output** (*+extra column*), **but makes me think there must be a better way...**

```
#split the number string
mydf$c <- strsplit(mydf$b,',')

#create new column of appropriate length
mydf$d <- 1:nrow(mydf)

#loop to get highest value into new column
for(i in 1:length(mydf$c)){
  mydf$d[i] <- max(as.numeric(unlist(mydf$c[i])))
}
```

Comment: Maybe `mydf$c <- vapply(strsplit(mydf$b, ","), function(x) max(as.numeric(x)), 1)` or `sapply(mydf$b, function(x) max(scan(text = x, sep = ",")))`

Comment: If you want to vectorize, I would go with `library(data.table) ; setDT(mydf)[, do.call(pmax, tstrsplit(b, ",", fixed = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE))]` OR just `do.call(pmax, tstrsplit(mydf$b, ",", fixed = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE))`